# Fetching data from more tahn one table in MySql Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to display more than one table from mysql in android app i used this php code to display one table

### PHP

```
<?php
include 'config1.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      $tem = $row;
      $json = json_encode($tem,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   }

} else {
   echo "0 results";
}

echo $json;
$conn->close();

?>
```

How i can use this code to display more than one table

Edit:
I want php code work with this Android code

### MainActivity

```
 public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    story_type = intent.getStringExtra("Story_Type");


    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://i-geeky.info/android/" + story_type + ".php";

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        ListItem_Rewayat GetDataAdapter2 = new ListItem_Rewayat();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setId(json.getString(id));

            GetDataAdapter2.setName(json.getString(name));

            GetDataAdapter2.seturl(json.getString(url));

            GetDataAdapter2.setimg(json.getString(img));

            GetDataAdapter2.setnum(json.getString(num));

            GetDataAdapter2.setsize(json.getString(size));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);

    }

    recyclerViewadapterRewayat = new Adapter_Rewayat(GetDataAdapter1, this);


    //RecyclerView needs a layout manager in order to display data so here we create one
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //Here we set the layout manager and the adapter to the listview
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterRewayat);



}
```

### ListItem

```
public class ListItem_Rewayat {

public String id;
public String name;
public String url;
public String img;
public String num;
public String size;


public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getid() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(String id1) {

    this.id = id1;
}


public String geturl() {

    return url;
}

public void seturl(String url1) {

    this.url = url1;
}

public String getimg() {

    return img;
}

public void setimg(String img1) {

    this.img = img1;
}

public String getnum() {

    return num;
}

public void setnum(String num1) {

    this.num = num1;
}
public String getsize() {

    return size;
}

public void setsize(String size1) {

    this.size = size1;
}

}
```

Comment: just add it to the query: `SELECT * FROM table1, table2 where table1.connector = table2.connector ORDER BY table1.id DESC` is that what you meen??

Comment: but your code will only send the _last_ item in your table, because you overwrite $tem and $json in every row.

Comment: Your android code will not work with multiple tables. Unless they have the same fields, but then the php needs to be different. We don't know what your tables look like.

Comment: tables have same fields

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a guess, but I think this is what you want:

```
//...
$table1 = Array();
$table2 = Array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  // get the result for first table and save it into an array ($table1)
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $table1[] = $row;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// just do the same for any other table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $table2[] = $row;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
// here you put together what you wanna return:
$return = Array('table1' => $table1, 
                'table2' => $table2);
// encode it
$json = json_encode($return,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $json;
```

**BUT:**
It would be better to encapsulate that into a function:

```
//...
function getTable($conn, $tableName) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $tableResult = Array();

    if ($result->num_rows >0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $tableResult[] = $row;
       }
    }
    return $tableResult;
}

$return = Array('table1' => getTable($conn, 'table1'), 
                'table2' => getTable($conn, 'table2')
          );
$json = json_encode($return,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo $json;
```

Finally: There are many db-classes available for free that do stuff like that for you. Also you might want to have a look at REST-API Kitss, which are also easy to find - and for free. You are doing work, that has been done a lot of times - and most of them better and more secure. But it's good to do it again if you're still learning.

Comment: not work with me i want like my code because it work with my json code in android app but for more tables

Comment: Then tell me what your special need is! Please edit your question what structure of json you're expecting.